# Cannot read property 'match' of undefined - prettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

I am using [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) and when click on a image, it show loading gif and image is not loading. I found this error on browser console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at h (jquery.prettyPhoto.js:7)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.prettyPhoto.js:7)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.complete (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:3)
    at l (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5)
    at x.fx.tick (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5)
```

How could I solve this?

**UPDATE**

I figured out the issue. The image is inside an anchor tag. If I use `$("div.news-text-detail a").prettyPhoto();` image is loading. This will apply effect for all anchor tags. But I need to apply this to **ONLY** image inside anchor tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.news-text-detail img").prettyPhoto();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettyPhoto/3.1.6/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettyPhoto/3.1.6/css/prettyPhoto.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="news-text-detail span12">
   <div style="text-align: justify;">
      <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
         <a href="http://i.imgur.com/mV7ezeo.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;">
            <img border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/mV7ezeo.jpg" data-original-height="384" data-original-width="800" height="305" width="640">
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: we need your code to help... this is a generic js error, can't do anything with this. Make a snippet.

Comment: [Include snippet](http://imgur.com/a/sjCS7)

Comment: What is imageanchor ? You're saying it has a meaning in your code but i can't see why. Can you add some CSS to snippet so we can see it complete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i really understand your problem but you need to prettyPhoto the a links only if they contains an img right ?

So i guess you can do it like this :

```
jQuery('div.news-text-detail img).closest('a').prettyPhoto();
```

First you look at the img, then you get his parent a and prettyphoto on the a.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I looking for.